# Trying to write/read CSV file with None objects for empty cells [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pymysql

I'm trying to read data in format CSV using pandas DataFrame so that the empty cells will be recognized as **None** values.

the delimiter is ',' and I have two of them wherever I need **None** value. for example, the row:

```
12345,'abc','abc',,,12,'abc'
```

Will be converted to a tuple and replaced to:

```
(12345,'abc','abc',None,None,12,'abc',)
```

I need it in order to insert data to MySQL later and I'm using cursor.execute() function with the query and the data

I have tried to load the CSV file to a DataFrame and replace but it is not supported:

```
chunk = chunk.replace(np.nan, None, regex=True)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not attain the meaning of the question completely but if it is in regards to CSV, why don't you have arbitrary values of your choice or even empty strings that you can then change later during the programme for when you want to write the data out or when you read.

Comment: I was looking for a quick way to write a simple pipeline that all he needs to do is to insert data directly from CSV file to MySQL.

I thought maybe there is an easy way to convert those numpy.null values used as empty cell in DataFrame to None in order to insert them later in a way they will be recognized as null values in the database.

Didn't find any easy way to do it so in the end I needed to iterate over the table and "rebuild" the entire row with conditions in the way I needed.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I did not originally fully understand it

Comment: Wait, suppose you instead have a loop go over the original CSV data, have your empty strings strictly equal none when you make it into a list via if statements, then turn the list into a tuple during run time, would that have not work?